# Classification systems for mathematics.

Tags: soft-question

Mathematics is a very broad topic nowadays, and it seems to be coming more and more obscure. I was wondering as to whether any organisations have implemented a classification system or organisational schematic for the differing branches of mathematics. For instance, one can separate into pure and applied, from pure one could see that geometry can be separated into analytic, discrete, differential, hyperbolic etc. It seems messy and a little all over the place, so I assume there must be one system set up somewhere. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AMS subject Classification is an well known one. If you are not aware of this, see here http://www.ams.org/msc/msc2010.html

Comment: That's perfect, thank you.